# MSBuild called by Process.Start() behaving differently between VS2010 and VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have both VS2010 and VS2013 installed and am trying to run a program that compiles a .net 4.0 solution by calling MSBuild (`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`).

For the record, the code that does this looks like:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = pathToMSBuild,
                Arguments = "C:\path\to\mySolution.sln /nr:false",
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
```

I've checked the .sln, which contains a .vcxproj and .csproj file, and these only contain references to `ToolsVersion=4.0`.

When I execute the program in VS2010 (or open cmd.exe and run the MSBuild command myself) it works fine and compiles the solution. However, when I run the same program using VS2013 I get the following error from MSBuild:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Micros
oft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFacto
ry" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll". Could not load file or assembly '
file:///C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v
12.0.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
. [C:\...\solution\myProject.vcxproj]
```

I found [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b767943e-8b69-469e-a38d-286662e562f6/build-error-with-visual-studio-2013microsoftcodeanalysistargets2145-error-?forum=visualstudiogeneral) on msdn that actually solved this for me - after commenting out the offending lines from this file, I can call MSBuild succesfully from VS2013. But I don't understand why this is relevant since I thought I was running a `v4.0` MSBuild to compile a project with `ToolsVersion=4.0`.

Presumably this is due to some environment variable getting set when I run/debug my program with VS2013? I can't find any details on the internet. Please could someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: The path is wrong, Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll is not located in that directory.  Don't solve problems by copying files, that just produces two problems.

Comment: Great point @HansPassant.. I gave the OP credit for not being cowboy enough to copy files? I hope my canonical points below lead OP to digging deeper

Comment: I am indeed not cowboy enough to just copy the files but unfortunately still confused by both your comments. I can see that Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll is missing but I guess my real question is why does it not complain about this when I run my program in VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the /v:diag switch to your arguments. This will cause msbuild to run with output verbosity set to diagnostic. This will show you the state of env vars and the app domain at the start of each call and might help you to identify differences.

Note - take this out when you're done as it will significantly slow down the build process.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The error is a **Could not load file or assembly** and  **The system cannot find the file specified .. .vcxproj**:

## Troubleshooting

Open [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and run the build process until it throws the error. Stop the trace when it fails and investigate ProcMon's (Filemon) log to see where the MSBuild is looking for the .vcxproj or .xyz files/assemblies it cant find. Solve that!!

## Solution

Put the file where its expected to be found.